# FileStore::OpenErr at memory location 0x012FED64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, crypto++

I am using a Crypto++ library for hashing a file. I got the error *`FileStore::OpenErr at memory location 0x012FED64`* at the line:

```
FileSource file(filename.c_str(), false, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(result)));
```

The code is:

```cxx
#include <iostream>
#include "..\cryptopp\sha.h"
#include "..\cryptopp\hex.h"
#include "..\cryptopp\files.h"
using namespace std;

string hashFile(string filename);

int main() {
    string shahash("");
    string fileName = "D:\test.txt";
    shahash = hashFile(fileName);
    cout << shahash << endl;
    return 0;
}

string hashFile(string filename)
{
    string result;
    SHA256 hash;
    FileSource file(filename.c_str(), false, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(result)));

    file.PumpAll();
    return result;
}
```

And the detail error is as below:

```
Exception thrown at 0x764B08B2 in myproject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::FileStore::OpenErr at memory location 0x012FED64.
Unhandled exception at 0x764B08B2 in myproject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::FileStore::OpenErr at memory location 0x012FED64.

The program '[13128] myproject.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The screenshot depicting the error is:

[image]

What could be the possible reason for this kind of error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string fileName = "D:\test.txt";
```

should be

```
string fileName = "D:\\test.txt";
```

`\t` is the tab character. I'm pretty sure you don't want that in your file name.

Answer (score 1):

May be check it out programmatically using errno? Add to start of your file:

```
#include <cerrno> // for errno
#include <cstring> // for strerror
```

And then wrap your throwing hashfile call into try:

```
try
{
    shahash = hashFile(fileName);
} 
catch(CryptoPP::FileStore::OpenErr const&)
{
    cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
    return 42;    
}
```

If nothing did make further failing calls in destructors during stack unwinding then errno tells to cout what was wrong with that file. Also you get rid of your unhandled exception crash.

My guess is that `"D:\test.txt"` is bad file name and you want `"D:\\test.txt"`

Comment: OP should be able to check the message supplied with `FileStore::OpenErr`. It will tell him the filename that failed to open. `errno` probably won't return more information because OP already knows there is an open error.

Comment: @jww the OpenErr tells that there was IO_ERROR with the file with name his odd file name that he already knows. Errno tells what was wrong with it.